# Call a function from class

Tags: python-3.x

I have two python file.
Unity.py, main.py

I want to call a function from main.py which is under a class

```
from unity import Unity
class down(Unity):
    def __init__(self,TOPIC):
      .
      .
    def xyz(self):
     .
     .
```

How to call xyz function in this main.py?

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to instantiate `down` class after that you can all the `xyz` function

```py
instance = down("topicname")
instance.xyz() # Call xyz function
```

Comment: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'TOPIC'

Comment: check edited answer